# Not restarting apache2

Tags: nginx, apache2, digital-ocean

Currently i am using nginx at digitalocean and i am new with it. I recored a domain to my droplet and try to create a sub domain of the main domain. I set up my virtual host and do other stuffs. Then when i  trying to restart **apache2**
it shows me an error i.e

> - Restarting web server apache2
>     (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>     address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could
>     not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available,
>     shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed. The
>     Apache error log may have more information.

I google for it but don't find any suitable answer. Then i want check who is using port 80. I ran a commond i.e

> ss -plnt sport eq :80

it shows me that two user is currently running on port 80. please check the image

[image]

**Now my question is**, 
Is this a normal scenario of port 80?

- If so then how to resolve the apache2 error?
- If not then how to remove another user by keeping one?

Hope i will get my answer soon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Listen ip:port` in both apache and nginx to make them run on same port, bot you should remember you have to use different ip adresses each program